# How to show connected query Load status in a pop-up/ alert message?

Tags: excel, vba, refresh, powerquery

I have a Query linked to an Excel spreadsheet. I want that the users can refresh the query and run VBA code once they click on a Refresh button.

Sometimes users do not have the access to the source data, so the query does not update properly. When they click on the refresh button it does not show any error message and continues to run the code without updating the query.

Is there any process to show the status that the query did not download the data?

Answer (score 0):

for error control you can use this:

```
Public Function example()
On Error GoTo Err_Control

' you code

Err_Control:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        If Err.Number = 1004 Then
            MsgBox "You do not have permission to access the data source." & Chr(13) & "Macro will be finished."
            Exit Function
        Else
            MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Iinside Err_Control you put the error handler.